# how do i make a event listener for a button that is in a forwach loop

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a *for each* loop where it loops through a table and the table has an *id* field which gets assigned to the button's *id*. I need to see which button gets clicked (I need to get the value of the *id*). the *id* of the table is not `1,2,3,4,5` it is either a **Q** or **A** with a number; e.g one button's *id* might be: **Q21**.

Comment: do buttons have same class name?

Comment: What have you tried? What has gone wrong? Because, you know, you should try and fail and then ask the question. Not just a "this is what I need tell me the answer"

Comment: @ThomasByy ive been trying for a day, nothing that i found helped  me, everytime i try the last id in the loop gets selected, i outputed a message to console and only the last button gets registered.

Comment: @mikewatawski yes they do!

Comment: What do you mean: `the table has a id field which gets assigned to the button's id` ?

Comment: @cssyphus yes i am.

Comment: @cssyphus i have a sql table which has a auto increment id, i have two types of buttons, and i in the loop i add a 'Q' for question or 'A' for answer as a prefix,
``<button id="Q{{$pastpaper->id}}" class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Question</button>
<button id="A{{$pastpaper->id}}" class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Answer</button>
``

Comment: did you try to use class name then apply some event listener and get attribute id?

Comment: @mikewatawski how do i do that? im pretty new to javascript

Comment: Do you mean there is a column where a button is put and the button has a data called id?  And you want to let a handler listened to the click events of these buttons and get the data then? If so, you should not use loop. Instead, you should use event delegation.  Listen to the click event on the table and check the current target which emits the event. If the current target is the button, run your logic.  Data `id` should be attached on the DOM elements through `dataset` attribute.

Comment: Improved formatting; poor grammar and spelling are not appropriate in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might get you started:

```js
$('table tr td button').click(function(){
  let tbl = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
  let row = $(this).closest('tr')[0].rowIndex;
  console.log(tbl+row);
});
```

```css
.h2{font-size:1.5rem;}
.h3{font-style:italic;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="h2">Table rowIndex is zero-based</div>
<div class="h3">(First row number is zero)</div>
<table id="Q">
  <tr><td>Row 1</td><td><button>Row 1</button></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 2</td><td><button>Row 2</button></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 3</td><td><button>Row 3</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark the answer as correct when you are able. *Good luck with your project.*

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the earlier answer before I saw your latest comment reply. This new answer might be closer to what you need. I will leave the first answer so you can refer to it later if you wish.

```js
$('table tr td button').click(function(){
  let buttId = this.id;
  console.log('You clicked: ' + buttId);
});
```

```css
.h2{font-size:1.5rem;}
.h3{font-style:italic;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="h2">This might be closer to your needs</div>
<table id="Q">
  <tr><td>Row 1</td><td><button id="Q1">Row 1</button></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 2</td><td><button id="Q2">Row 2</button></td></tr>
  <tr><td>Row 3</td><td><button id="Q3">Row 3</button></td></tr>
</table>
```